# Manatee.Trello: Webhook Code Sample

Tags: manatee.trello

I am looking for a code sample on how to use `Manatee.Trello Webhook` feature.

I found some documentation here: https://bitbucket.org/gregsdennis/manatee.trello/wiki/Webhooks, but it's not clear enough for me.

It only demonstrates how to create a `Webhook`, but doesn't demonstrate how the real-time updates are received and processed. Tried the `Updated` event on the `Webhook`, `Card` and `Actions` - but clearly I am not doing something correctly.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article demonstrates webhooks in general:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/09/04/introducing-microsoft-asp-net-webhooks-preview/

Basically, there is a NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Trello` that you can install that does all the heavy lifting.

Once the NuGet package is installed I can override the built-in Controller and use `Webhook.ProcessNotification()` as **Greg Dennis** had suggested.

Hope someone out there finds this useful.

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't even know that was out there.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set up the web portion yourself.  This can be done with an [`ApiController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) (or others).

Once you receive a POST message, read the content as a string (don't deserialize), and pass that to `Webhook.ProcessNotification()`.  Manatee.Trello well take care of the rest.

This will trigger the `Updated` events.

**EDIT**
I have created some better docs.  Here is the example you seek!

https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Trello/examples/webhook.html#processing-a-webhook-notification

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Added a more detailed answer.